# How does correctly find elements of a webpage with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

I practice with Facebook,

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();


driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

after successful logining I attempt to send message. But I can not find message area:

```
WebElement selectMessages = driver.findElement(By.id("fbMessagesFlyout"));
        selectMessages.click();


        WebElement elementMess = driver.findElement(By.id("q"));
        elementMess.sendKeys("Dalia");
        elementMess.submit();
```

This code just deploys javascript with messages on the header and then send search request also at the fb header. 
How do I can find correct link to a dialig page and then find there text aria?

Comment: Please attach the html part of this section.

Comment: you could use autoIt to identify the names/ids/classes etc. of a specific WebElement. Or even look at the pageLayout..

Comment: It's pretty big, it's common html part of facebook homepage.

Comment: Have you used a `WebDriverWait` to "wait" for it? Are you sure you cannot do this using a native API?

Comment: This code is working but it's make not particular task. I don't know how to find current element, I look to the pageLayout, but i see there only elements of the fb header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This WORKS!!

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/login.php");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("youridhere@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("yourpassword");
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement msgframe = driver.findElement(By.id("fbMessagesJewel"));
    msgframe.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By
            .className("messagesContent"));
    element.get(0).click();
    WebElement chat = driver.findElement(By.className("fbNubFlyoutFooter"));
    chat.findElement(By.tagName("textarea")).sendKeys("Hi");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have few qustions: how do you find `className("fbNubFlyoutFooter")` and `tagName("textarea")` I looking for it on the layouts with ctrl+u in browser and haven't found. Your code just put "hi" to the area, how do I can submit?

Comment: I use Chrome debugger only; But this is not the case. You can do the same on other browsers too. I dunno why u couldn't :(